# Show that $x^T A x = x^T sym(A) x$

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

Starting from

$x^T sym(A) x = x^T (0.5A^T + 0.5A)x = 0.5x^TA^Tx + 0.5x^TAx$

Now I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Hint: suppose $B$ is the antisymmetric part of $A$, $B^T= - B$, what can you say about $x^T B x$? Perhaps it is easier to see in components if you are familiar with the notation, $x^T B x= x_i\  B_{ij} \ x_j=?$ summed over $i$ and $j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty much done, since for a real number $r$,
$$r^{T}=r,$$
so what can you say about the real number $x^{T}A^{T}x$?